# Run a informatica workflow every hour but only in business hours?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How to run an Informatica workflow every hour but only on business days?
Skip Saturday and Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any scheduler external to Informatica (like ControlM, Tivoli etc) and want to do it purely in Informatica...perhaps you can do something like attached. It would execute on holidays since I am not sure if Informatica supports customizing at that level.

Workflow > Schedulers > New > Schedule > See image below for details.[image]

Answer (score 0):

we can do this using unix shell script and crontab

1. create shell script which runs the workflow using pmcmd.
2. create crontab which will run this shell script hourly basis and within your business hours.